# MySQL and PHP parsing strange string

Tags: php, android, mysql, string, post

I'm exporting tables from Android(SQLite) to MYSQL using PHP to communicate with the server (I use `XAMPP` as tool).

I have a table in `sqlite` with a string field(named "Start"), which tells me the current time in a format that I specially designed. A example is: 0:03:14 -- 2013/8/12. I give this information to the server using `HttpPost` in Android.

Here comes the problem. I create the table for mysql using "varchar(50)" type for "Start" field for example. When I'm inserting into the table, I got the next message using JSON:

```
08-12 16:51:25.383: D/MYSQL(26304): jsonResult {"phpError":"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':36:12 -- 2013\/8\/6, \r\n\t18:36:17 -- 2013\/7\/6, 30, 57)' at line 2","Success":0,"Message":"Oops! Couldnt upload data","Start":"18:36:12 -- 2013\/8\/6"}
```

As you see, the original start string is 18:36:12, however, in the error message it appears "to use near ':36:12" so it seems it has some problem to "parse" the string (?). Anyone knows whats happening? Should I use different type for this field?

This is my PHP file:

```
<?php

    $response = array();

    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mobile_metadata(ID int, Acc int, Mag int, Gyr int, Temperature int, Grav int, 
    Light int, LinAcc int, Pressure int, Proximity int, Humidity int, RotVec int, Format varchar(50), Start varchar(50),
    Finish varchar(50), First int, Last int);";

    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);

    //Data succesfully created/was already created
    if($result1){

        $id = $_POST['id']; $acc = $_POST['Acc']; $mag = $_POST['Mag']; $gyr = $_POST['Gyr']; $temperature = $_POST['Temperature']; $grav = $_POST['Grav'];
        $light = $_POST['Light']; $linAcc = $_POST['LinAcc']; $pressure = $_POST['Pressure']; $proximity = $_POST['Proximity']; $humidity = $_POST['Humidity'];
        $rotVec = $_POST['RotVec']; $format = $_POST['Format']; $start = $_POST['Start']; $finish = $_POST['Finish']; $first = $_POST['First']; 
        $last = $_POST['Last'];

        $sql2 = "INSERT into mobile_metadata(ID, Acc, Mag, Gyr, Temperature, Grav, LinAcc, Pressure, Proximity, Humidity, RotVec, Format, Start, Finish,
        First, Last) VALUES ($id, $acc, $mag, $gyr, $temperature, $grav, $light, $linAcc, $pressure, $proximity, $humidity, $rotVec, $format, $start, 
        $finish, $first, $last);";

        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

        //Data uploaded
        if($result2){

            $response['Success'] = 1;
            $response['Message'] = "Data uploaded succesfuly";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

        //Couldnt upload data
        else{

            $response["phpError"] = mysql_error();
            $response['Success'] = 0;
            $response['Message'] = "Oops! Couldnt upload data";
            $response['Start'] = $_POST['Start'];
            echo json_encode($response);

        }
    }

    //Couldnt create the table
    else{

        $response["phpError"] = mysql_error();
        $response["Success"] = 0;
        $response["Message"] = "Oops! Couldnt create the table";
        echo json_encode($response);

    }
    ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

None of your fields are quoted, and you're **DIRECTLY** inserting user-provided data in your query. You are begging for [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

ANY of the fields which are text/non-numeric MUST BE quoted in the values section, e.g..

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (textfield) VALUES ($textfield);
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (textfield) VALUES ('$textfield');
                                          ^--        ^-- note the quotes.
```

Comment: That's up to the OP to fix. You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him do proper defensive programming if he doesn't want to.

Comment: sure. but i find your comment misleading. you are warning about sql injection, but give a solution that half solves the problem. without proper knownledge or experience, one would take your solution and stop worrying about sql injection or user input sanitation

Comment: Or perhaps we should stop handing people nicely gift-wrapped solutions and force them to think. You can beat someone over the head all you want with quoting and escaping, but until they understand **WHY** they're necessary, they'll just be doing cargo cult programming and polluting this site with questions they could have easily answered themselves if they just understand WHAT they're doing.

Comment: I agree that the solution I posted is too much in term of gift-wrapping. (and that's an issue with a lot of answers posted on SO). But my point is that your answer is in 2 parts (of which both are correct. there is clearly a risk of injection, and non-numerical fields must be quoted if used directly), and the risk is that someone would look further and make a connection between quoting inputs and preventing sql injection.

Comment: I didnt have any idea about bobby tables, but after reading and reading I finally understood everything! I think it was a good idea to give me the solution and to make me think about bobby tables and its problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not quoting and not escaping your inputs. It calls for SQL injection.

Don't use `mysql`. `mysqli` includes methods to properly prevent SQL injection (and stop worrying about SQL quoting and escaping):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into mobile_metadata(ID, Acc, Mag, Gyr, 
    Temperature, Grav, LinAcc, Pressure, Proximity, Humidity, RotVec, Format,
    Start, Finish, First, Last) VALUES 
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
$stmt.bind_params($id, $acc, $mag, $gyr, $temperature, $grav, $light, $linAcc,
        $pressure, $proximity, $humidity, $rotVec, $format, $start, $finish, 
        $first, $last);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: So I should totally forget about mysql language and always use mysqli? Is there a big difference? (I mean about sintaxys).

Comment: I only have one doubt more...keeping in mind all this dangerous stuff of using mysql api and the huge amount of tutorials over the net based on it...how is that possible? I mean, it should be kind deprecated or at least less used!

Comment: Ok, I just found the answer to my question seeing the fields "Recommended Api" and "Feature comparision" in the link you just gave me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a varchar field for time stamp information in MySQL. That kind of data is very hard to manipulate.  Instead use the `DATETIME` data type.  Then you can do stuff like

```
 mytable.finish + INTERVAL 10 SECOND
```

and other cool date computations.

As you insert stuff into your MySQL database use the `STR_TO_TIME` function, explained here.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

For your timestamps formatted like this:  0:03:14 -- 2013/8/12 ... you can use `STR_TO_DATE` as follows.

```
 STR_TO_DATE('0:03:14 -- 2013/8/12', '%k:%i:%s -- %Y/%c/%e')
```

To do this in your program, try something like this in your SQL statement.

```
 STR_TO_DATE(%finish, '%k:%i:%s -- %Y/%c/%e')
```

Other people answering have pointed out the SQL injection hazard.  Be careful: there are badguys out there who really want to pwn your MySQL server.

Comment: I really dont need to do any date computations with the information in MYSQL database but I´ll consider to change it anyway. Thanks for the advice!